# slidy presentation rmarkdown: logo and mainfont

Tags: html, r

I'm creating a slidy presentation with rmarkdown.

I have the following YAML:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Blu"
date: '2023-08-17'
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    theme: cerulean
    logo: logo.png
    mainfont: Arial

---
```

And these slides:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
````

### R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

### Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

### Slide with R Output

```
summary(cars)
```

### Slide with Plot

```
plot(pressure)
```

My problems:

1. When knit the logo doesn't appear anywhere. Why?
2. If I want to introduce another logo in the begining of each slide title (top-left before the first letter of each title) how can I do that?
3. Why the function in the YAML "mainfont:Arial" doesn't works?